VS Code crashing in Cent Os 7 Container
Base Setup :

Kde installed
X Window System installed
Code v 1.85 installed
TigerVnc Server installed

So I have connect to my container via ssh and then use the container GUI with RealVnc viewer.It is a bit laggy but it is fine.
In order to run vs code --no-sandbox flag is required.It runs well but starts crashing when extensions like jupyter are installed.
What errors I see (Crash logs and Dialog boxes) :

Crashes with signal 5 and signal 11.(Permission denied and Segmentation faults)
Vs code crashed with error : 133
Render frame was disposed before WebFrameMain could be accessed
Org.freedesktop.Portal.Settings not found (It is just like a warning seen irrespective of crash)
Lots of core dumps are generated as well.

So is there a way I can run VS Code smoothly inside the container without using --privileged flag?
Also the container is not mounted to cgroups can that be responsible as well for this crashing ?
Tried changing versions of VS Code to check stability.All are unstable.
Tried portable vs code as well which does not require installation just extracting from tarball.It is unstable as well.
